# Conditional component rendering using switch

Tags: react-native

I have created 3 buttons in react native. I have stored images in three different components. I want that when i click on first button, it show the image stored in first component and so on . I want to use switch case statement. I dont want to use any library like tab navigators.

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
 Platform,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View,
 Alert,
 Button,
 TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

import first from "./components/first";
import second from "./components/second";
import third from "./components/third";

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
   render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.wrapper1}>
           <Text>Button 1</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.wrapper2}>
         <Text>Button 2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.wrapper3}>
        <Text>Button 3</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
      );
    }
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
   alignItems: "flex-start",
   flexDirection: "row"
  },
   wrapper1: {
   borderWidth: 1,
   borderColor: "black",
   backgroundColor: "red",
   paddingHorizontal: 40,
   paddingVertical: 15
   },
  wrapper2: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    paddingVertical: 15
   },
  wrapper3: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    paddingVertical: 15
  }
   });
```

first.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
 Platform,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View,
 Alert,
 Button,
 TouchableOpacity
 } from "react-native";

export default class first extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: "http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png" 
}}
    />
  </View>
   );
 }
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
   alignItems: "flex-start",
   flexDirection: "row"
   }
   });
```

second.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
 Platform,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View,
 Alert,
 Button,
 TouchableOpacity
 } from "react-native";

export default class second extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: "http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png" 
}}
    />
  </View>
   );
 }
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
   alignItems: "flex-start",
   flexDirection: "row"
   }
   });
```

third.js

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import {
     Platform,
     StyleSheet,
     Text,
     View,
     Alert,
     Button,
     TouchableOpacity
      } from "react-native";

    export default class third extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: "http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png" 
}}
    />
  </View>
   );
 }
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
   alignItems: "flex-start",
   flexDirection: "row"
   }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean way consist in :

- Storing the pictures url in an array
- Use a state to keep the current picture index
- Call one time the **Image** component, with a different url depending of the state
- Add buttons to change the state

I created a working example :

https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so-53608978

**Edit** : if you really want to keep different components, and to use a switch here is a working example :

https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so-53608978-2

Comment: Its correct. But can you please explain using switch case. and i want to keep images in different components

Comment: I just edited my answer to add a working example matching your requirements.